# Can't connect on postgres in docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm using Docker on Windows to use in local a postgres database. I made two docker container: one for the database called pg and another called pgadmin with pgadmin4.
After inspected pg, I connected pgadmin4 in 172.17.0.3:5432 and it works.
Now time to code but...

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on host "172.17.0.3" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I read a lot of questions like that, but i can't figure it out. Doesn't seem, to me, like a problem generated in pg_hba.conf for the denied connection, because in this case pgadmin should not work, right?
(But if is a problem with pg_hba.conf where I can find it? In the docker installation folder I did't find it)

I put my python code here but don't seems the problem:

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database = 'example',
    user = 'username',
    password = 'secretpassword',
    host = '172.17.0.3', # default port is 5432 so it's not necessary
)
```

Upgrade edit:
I found the configurations
In postgresql.conf the listen_addresses = '*', that is correct.
In pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Comment: How are you starting the two containers?  You should usually ignore the container-private IP addresses; for example, they'll change if you delete and recreate the container, or run them on a different Docker network.

Comment: @DavidMaze I think I don't understand the question... I know the IP change when I start the containers, so I inspect every time to be sure that it hasn't change (the only difference that I noticed is the inversion of the two address one on .12 and the other on .13). If you ask this, I believe that you have another and better way to do it, correct? Anyway I followed this tutorial to be sure that I'm on the correct way and do the same things https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QNL7_i-ay8

Comment: If the two containers are on the same Docker network or launched in the same `docker-compose.yml` file then you can use the container names as hostnames.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `docker run` and the `--expose` parameter to expose your ports, on each container.

Another command you can run is `docker network connect` which allows you to connect a container to a network, so if two containers are on the same network, they should be able to communicate with each other.

The usage is `docker network connect [OPTIONS] NETWORK CONTAINER`

One advantage of using the `docker network create` command is to be able to create an `--ip-range` so to specify ip addresses to be used on the network.

Afterwards you can assign a container to have a specific ip address, `docker network connect`. If the container was not on the network for example, the ip address would not be reassigned to another container on the network.

More information in the docker documentation,
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/

Comment: `docker run --expose` doesn't really do anything and won't help this issue.  Can you provide a more complete explanation of how Docker networks would help?